# Evaluating $\int_{s^{-1/n}}^{\infty}v^2\exp{\left[-\left(\frac{l}{v} + m v\right)^2\right]}dv$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

I am trying to evaluate the following 
$$I = \int_0^s u^{-3n-1} \exp{\left[-\left(l u^n + \frac{m}{u^{n}}\right)^2\right]}\,du,$$
where $l, m$ and $n$ are positive constants.

I tried to substitute $v = u^{-n}$, and got the following integral
$$I =\frac{1}{n} \int_{s^{-1/n}}^{\infty} v^{2} \exp{\left[-\left(\frac{l}{v} + m v\right)^2\right]}\,dv.$$
I was trying to follow in Oliver's footsteps in this [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1861053/23874), but I am not sure if that is completely possible with this integrand.

**Edit**

Upon integration by parts once we get
\begin{eqnarray}
I &=& \frac{v^2\sqrt{\pi } e^{-4 l m} \left(\text{erfc}\left(\frac{l}{v}-m v\right)-e^{4 l m} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{l}{v}+m v\right)\right)}{4 m}|_{s^\frac{-1}{n}}^{\infty} - \frac{1}{n} \int_{s^\frac{1}{n}}^{\infty} v \exp{\left[-\left(\frac{l}{v} + m v\right)^2\right]}\,dv\\
\end{eqnarray}
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What kind of problem do you face after Olivier Oloa's answer ?

Comment: @Comic Book Guy Please check that with the change of variable $v=u^{-n}$ you rather obtain the factor $v^2$ in the integrand *not* $v^{-2}$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, the closest integral to this, I have seen solved is the one in that question, in Olivier Oloa's answer, I wish that it is possible to find a substitution to reduce this integral to something so that it is possible to use the identity, which was highlighted there. Intuitively, I fear that this will not be possible, which leaves me in bad spot. All I seek is some hints/pushes in the right direction.

Comment: @ComicBookGuy There is a closed-form for this integrall too.

Comment: @ComicBookGuy I think there is another typo in your second integral of the above question, isn't it $s^{-1/n}$ for the lower bound instead of $s^{1/n}$?

Comment: @ComicBookGuy I suggest we delete our comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may start with the following evaluation, for $a>0$, $b>0$, 
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_a^\infty e^{\large-bx^2-\frac1{x^2}}\,dx
\\\\&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\left(e^{2\sqrt{b}}+e^{-2\sqrt{b}} \right)}{4\sqrt{b}}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{-2\sqrt{b}}}{4\sqrt{b}}\text{erf}\left(\frac1{a}-a\sqrt{b}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{2\sqrt{b}}}{4\sqrt{b}}\text{erf}\left(\frac1{a}+a\sqrt{b}\right). \tag1
\end{align}
$$ By differentiating both sides with respect to $b$ one gets the closed form :
$$
\int_a^\infty x^2e^{\large-bx^2-\frac1{x^2}}\,dx=-\partial_b\left( \text{RHS}\right). \tag2
$$ Then, by the change of variable $v=lx$, one obtains
$$
\int_{\large s^{-1/n}}^{\infty} v^{2} \exp{\left[-\left(\frac{l}{v} + m v\right)^2\right]}\,dv=l^3e^{\large-2ml}\int_{\large \frac{s^{-1/n}}{l}}^\infty x^2e^{\large-(ml)^2x^2-\frac1{x^2}}\,dx \tag3
$$ and one may conclude with  $(2)$.

Comment: Thank you. You are like a modern era Ramanujan :-)

Comment: @Comic Book Guy Your smiley at the end should be *infinitely* bigger ;-)